# Querying complex user permissions in routes, controllers, and views

Tags: ember.js, permissions

I'm building an EmberJS app with a two layer permissions schema. Each user has many roles and workspaces:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    ...
    roles       : DS.hasMany('role', {async: true}),
    workspaces  : DS.hasMany('workspace', {async: true}),
    ...
});
```

Each role has an array of permissions and belongs to a workspace:

```
var Role = DS.Model.extend({
    ...
    permissions : DS.attr(),
    workspace   : DS.belongsTo('workspace', {async: true}),
    ...
});
```

The permissions are returned to the Role model as an array of objects:

```
permissions: [
    {object:permission, id:prm_yRPZ1qlE, name:administrate, display_name:Administrate},
    {object:permission, id:prm_QVPvJPry, name:projects.index, display_name:View All Projects},
    {object:permission, id:prm_vxPdB7QE, name:projects.store, display_name:Create Project},
    ...
]
```

A user can be signed into one of their workspaces, which has unique permissions from other workspaces. What I need the ability to do, is to query the user's capabilities based on the workspace currently signed into. For example, a user may be signed into `/workspace/:id/` and I need to be able to do something like `this.userCan('View All Projects')` and have it query their permissions for the current workspace. Note: I've got the current user bound to the session, so doing `this.get('session.user')` is a breeze.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to query the user's permissions from any route or controller. Would a mixin be the logical choice for this task, a method on the User model, or a utility function be a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method on the user model sounds like the easiest solution for sure.  The biggest issue I see is the fact that your roles are async.  That means either you need to guarantee that the roles already exist, or your `user.can('delete')` would need to return a promise due roles not being guaranteed to be resolved yet.

Comment: What if I make the roles embedded? Our API is fluid, so I can easily switch to that and use the EmbeddedRecordsMixin. The problem I'm running into there, is even though the records are added to the store, trying to query them off the user model throws an error. See: http://d.pr/i/7TO7

Comment: Can you reproduce that issues using this jsbin, it'll probably be easier than having you put up all of your json and workflow.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qabaf/1/edit

Comment: Well, I tried, but http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fuxuq/1/edit?js,output is throwing a 404 when running the mock ajax request. Wanna have a peek?

Comment: Whoops! Had the mockjax url wrong. Have a look now.

Comment: k, so that looks awesome, but it's working, unlike your site, right?

Comment: That is correct, but I found a stray call to the user.roles object in a template. Removed that and all good. Thank you sir!

Comment: I thought I had this figured, but I'm still getting this error saying all the records are not loaded. I can see the role records in ember-data and they look good. The workspace relationship is there. The user records are borked. They're there, but the role relationship isn't being associated correctly.